# How to build OpenSSL in release mode with symbols?

Tags: visual-c++, debugging, openssl, pdb-files

I generally build my openssl libs by doing this:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN32
ms\do_masm 
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak 
nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak test
```

For debugging minidumps, I'd like to get a pdb file for the 2 dlls (while still building them in "release" mode).  I've added /Zi to the CFLAGS part of ms\ntdll.mak, but I still get "Binary was not built with debug information" when I look at the in-memory modules in the visual studio debugger.  Am I missing a step?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

link needs /DEBUG.

Comment: `LFLAGS` already has `/debug`. Where does the `.pdb` file end up?

Comment: `LFLAGS` needs `/debug` but `CFLAGS` also needs `/Zi`
If ever in doubt, this is a great resource for all the flags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference